# Significance of a exponential mean

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, exponential-distribution

> A manufacturer of bulbs claim that they have a lifetime of 2000 burning hours. A sample of 100 tubes were taken at random and tested for burning. Mean life was found to be 1950 with SD of 150. Can the manufacturers claim be accepted at 5% significance level?

I only can think of using the exponential distribution but I do not have an idea as to how the hypothesis can be solved. Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: The grey text does not clarify whether the 2000 burning hours are _maximum_ or _average_. Also, since no distribution is assumed a priori, it appears that one can only appeal to the central limit theorem and approximate the distribution of the sample mean by a normal distribution.

Comment: and use Z tables to test the hypothesis?

Comment: In that case, yes.